# Please translate Gemara - Aramaic word מקני

Tags: grammar-dikduk, translation, aramaic, bava-metzia

In בבא מציעא [daf 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.33b.11), the very beginning of the Gemara on המפקיד.  The Gemara says מקני ליה.  The Artscroll English edition, vowelizes מקני as *mak-nay*.  What are the precise possible translation(s) of מקני ליה?

- Does the *yud* in מקני signify that the subject (the one(s) being מקנה) is plural?  i.e. they are מקנה
- Or can it refer to the items being transferred, leaving the subject singular - i.e. he is מקנה the items
- does ליה have to mean "to him" (i.e. to the recipient), or could it be referring to the item being transferred - as it "they are מקנה it" with ליה corresponding to "it"

thx

- "He conveys ownership to him"
- "He conveys ownership of it" (i.e. ליה refers to the item whose ownership is being transferred)
- "He conveys ownership of them (the items) to him"
- "They convey ownership to him"

Comment: @Kazibácsi - thanks - what does / could the yud with צרי (tzay-ray)  indicate?

Comment: See answer. (If it helps, please also consider accepting.)

Comment: Just one more Q - is it possible that the yud refers to plural - "they transfer the כפל to him"?

Comment: There is a final י both in singular and plural, but in your question it is clearly in singular. See this one for example: https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.156b.2

Comment: @Kazibácsi - thanks! I clicked accept- (1) is it impossible to be plural , b/c some learn that it's going on חז"ל - בית דין are the ones who grant him ownership.  (2) Also please explain how the yud in this aramaic word compares to the hebrew conjugation.  is it in place of the ה (hebrew would be מקנה ליה) or does the aramaic also use the ה, with the yud indicating something in addition?  (3) Lastly, how would the aramaic look if it were to say "they transferred to him"?

Comment: You can only go for sure if the personal pronoun is written there or in a continuous case there's a הוו, otherwise the two forms are identical (see examples I sent). The translations I saw confirmed my understanding that it was in singular, but Rashi explains it using a general "owners" term. In Hebrew it should be either ֹמַקְנֶה לו or ֹמַקְנִים לו.

Comment: @Kazibácsi:  Thanks doubly - (a) for the patient translations and (b) for pointing out what I overlooked in Rashi - namely that he learns that it's plural.  Which is especially curious b/c in terms of pshat I think the 2 options of who is transferring the rights to the shomer would be either the owner or beis din.  So since Rashi is learning it's the owner, it's strange that feel the need for the plural as the singular would have seemed to be more likely grammatically (if I understood you correctly) and fits in better with his pshat (owner)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hebrew and the Aramaic verbs in this case share the root קנ"ה. In the [paal](https://www.pealim.com/dict/1913-liknot/) form (קָנָה) it means to *buy* or *obtain* something. ArtScroll helps you with the *patach,* which suggests a causative, [hifil](https://www.pealim.com/dict/1915-lehaknot/) form (הִקְנָה), that is *"make someone obtain,"* which we rather say as *provide, transfer* etc. See the *hifil* section of Jastrow's [entry](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%99_%C2%B2?lang=bi) on the verb and also refer to the [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA#%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B5%D7%9C_(%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D6%B4%D7%A4%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9C)) or other [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159264452X).

Therefore, the verbatim translation of דמקני ליה כפילא is *because* (-ד) *(he is the) transferrer of* (מקני) *double* (כפילא) *to him* (ליה). So the י is a part of the present participle in the singular masculine case. For a proper translation see [Soncino](http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_33.html#PARTb) or [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.33b.11). In [Succah 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.46b.9) you can see various forms of the same verb, which may help.